# ExtJS6: Partial App load for special request that always opens in a new window

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs7

We have a ExtJS7 app, that for special requests like reset password, that always opens a new tab via email reset link, get loaded in full. We would like to load only few pages that are needed to load for these kind of request

Is there a way in ExtJS that would only load a particular page and its dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen tutorials on this subject in official documentation. Myself did the following - just created another app (or bundle) for logging. The backend is responsible for the logic of what to display (loginapp or mainapp) - in the absence of a session, the user receives the app login

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You can make another app - each app is a page, and will have its own packaged dependencies.

That's the easiest approach. A more complicated approach is to break your application into several ExtJS packages. You can then configure the app.json to exclude all of the packages from the micro loader. You then need to load these packages dynamically, presumably after logging in.

Doing this, though, is extremely complicated, and almost certainly not worth doing.